# Font selector for Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo UI doesn't have a font selector (a dialog to select font name, size, bold, underline, etc). But all these are in the text editor toolbar, [as seen here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/all-tools).

Any ideas how to "extract" these from the toolbar and make them available to be used individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI currently does not have such font-selector widget. However you can try to implement your own custom widget and extend the framework in your own way. How to create a basic widget is covered in the docs [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/widgets/create-custom-kendo-widget).

Comment: any idea why Telerik didin't include a font selector in Kendo UI?

Comment: Well in order to modify the styles of an object it should be related to Kendo. The only place where you need to modify whatever is typed is the Editor widget. There are also not any requests on the [feedback portal](http://feedback.kendoui.com/), it sounds like you are the only one who needs such.

Comment: I need it to have the end user customize grid cells